# How do I do the following Linq / Lambda code?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

*Note: pseduo code and fake-thought-up-on-the-spot classes/properties ... to protect the innocent*

I'm trying to retrieve the `Person` instance, where the person has a particular name ... as an `IQueryable` result.

Given the following code...

```
public class Person
{
    public ICollection<PersonDetails> PersonDetails { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

how can I retrieve a `Person`, who has the name 'Fred' ?

I was trying (which failed) ....

```
public static IQueryable<Person> WithName(this IQueryable<Person> value, 
                                          string name)
{
    return value.Where(x => x.PersonDetails.Where(y => y.Name == name));
}
```

.. and that doesn't compile.

Any clues, peeps?

Comment: How did it fail? Did you get any compiler error here?

Comment: Am I missing something, or why does a person have more than one name?

Comment: @Timbo: I don't know, but I guess it could be a Chinese person who has both a Chinese name and an English name?

Comment: Guys -> read the *Note* .. it's not really person/person-details (in my real code) .. i just made that up to protect what i'm doing (read: NDA's, etc).

Comment: It fails to compile because the inner Where returns an `IEnumerable<PersonDetails>` but the outer Where expects a predicate, means a Lambda expression which returns a `bool` and there is no implicit conversion between those two types.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `Any` instead of the second `Where`:

```
public static IQueryable<Person> WithName(this IQueryable<Person> value, 
                                          string name)
{
    return value.Where(x => x.PersonDetails.Any(y => y.Name == name));
}
```

Comment: Cheers. I _always_ get it mixed up. I initially tried `Any` and then `Where` but that failed of course ... so .. cheers! works :)